# Accessing Nested Dictionary - Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I have below Dictionary those values I am pulling from aws S3 bucket -

```
{u'Policy': u'{"Version":"2012-10-17","Statement":[{"Sid":"AddPerm","Effect":"Allow","Principal":"*","Action":"s3:GetObject","Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::elliemaetestbucket1/*"},{"Sid":"AddPerm1","Effect":"Allow","Principal":"*","Action":"s3:GetObject","Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::elliemaetestbucket1/*"}]}'}
```

I want to read "**Sid**" value and compare it with a string that I am getting from my yaml file. Dictionary can have multiple sids but I need to stop where my sid matches with the string that I am pulling from yaml. I am sure I am missing something very simple. But I have tried almost all the solutions most of the time I get unicode object not callable  error.
Can somebody please provide some direction on how I can access it. I know this would be something very simple but I am sorry I am stuck at this from 2 days.

Comment: You ain't gonna get anywhere without parsing the JSON from `your_data["Policy"]`.

Comment: What is the type of the data returned from S3?  What line of code gives you that "Not callable"  error.  If its a unicode string,  use json.dumps to create a regular json and then extract "Sid"

Comment: Data returned from s3 is Dictionary type. it returns Current_policy which consists of above dict that I mentioned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data's `Policy` key holds a literal JSON, you have to parse it first before you can access its nested fields:

```
import json

policy = json.loads(your_data["Policy"])

print(policy["Statement"][0]["Sid"])  # Sid of the first Statement
print(policy["Statement"][1]["Sid"])  # Sid of the second Statement
```

Comment: yayyy I knew it I was doing some stupidity. Thank you so much for your help I really appreciate.